# Writing floats into a csv file but floats become a string

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I am writing a dataframe into a csv as follows:

```
appended_Dimension.to_csv("outputDimension.csv")
```

The `dataframe` is as follows:

```
     Cameroun    Rwanda     Niger    Zambia      Mali    Angola  Ethiopia  
ECON  0.056983  0.064422  0.047602  0.070119  0.048395  0.059233  0.085559   
FOOD  0.058250  0.046348  0.048849  0.043527  0.049064  0.013157  0.081436   
ENV   0.013906  0.004013  0.010519  0.001973  0.005360  0.023010  0.008469   
HEA   0.041496  0.078403  0.040154  0.054466  0.029954  0.053007  0.061761   
PERS  0.056687  0.021978  0.062655  0.056477  0.087056  0.089886  0.043747
```

The output is  as follows:

[image]

I d like to write data in a float format so i can process it in csv directly. How can i do that please?

Comment: What program are you opening the csv in?

Comment: I am not using any program to open the csv. I am just looking to do quick manipulations in the raw file but it turns out that it is not possible to sum or plot values as they are all strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep it as float inside the csv. The csv will treat everything as strings. You must load your data from the csv and perform the relevant operations then save it back. You cannot manipulate it while it is present inside the csv.

Comment: Thanks i never knew that. I may have to paste the values in an excel file before plotting them i guess but i am still not sure whether they will stay strings and convert to floats

Comment: You can simply load the data into the pandas dataframe, that way they will retain their datatypes and then you can make use of matplotlib in order to plot the data.

Comment: Using matplolib is exactly what i am looking to avoid at this moment. I have plotted in matplolib extensively but in excel it is faster and easier. Hence why iam doing what i am doing

Comment: If you load the file using some kind of software like Libre or Google sheets or Microsoft Excel, as far as I know it will retain the datatypes.

Comment: Unfortunately even Excel does not retains the datatypes. i have saved CSVs in the past with float values and it is the first time i am not able to work with them in the raw file

Comment: Then I would say its better to make use of either matplotlib or pandas' own plotting functions. You can have a look at Kaggle on how to do proper data visualization using pandas quickly for any random dataset.